# cannot find symbol symbol:class ProtocolMessageEnum

Tags: ant, javac

On compiling the source code of [five-server](http://code.google.com/p/five/wiki/AccessingTheSource) I run into following errors

```
vickey@home:~/code/five-server$ ant dist
Buildfile: build.xml

guess-target:

-maybe-dist-win32:

-maybe-dist-macosx:

-maybe-dist-linux:

dist-clean:

init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/vickey/code/five-server/build/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/vickey/code/five-server/build/test-classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/resources

build-props:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/resources/org/devtcg/five

-checkprotoc:

protoc:
     [echo] Compiling protobufs into Java classes...

compile:
    [javac] Compiling 46 source files to /home/vickey/code/five-server/build/classes
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/src/main/java/org/devtcg/five/server/HttpServer.java:50: warning: sun.misc.BASE64Decoder is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    [javac] import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
    [javac]                ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:2538: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ProtocolMessageEnum
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         implements com.google.protobuf.ProtocolMessageEnum {
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:2735: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:2746: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:2757: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:2768: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:2780: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:2560: package com.google.protobuf.Internal does not exist
    [javac]       public static com.google.protobuf.Internal.EnumLiteMap<Type>
    [javac]                                                 ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:2564: package com.google.protobuf.Internal does not exist
    [javac]       private static com.google.protobuf.Internal.EnumLiteMap<Type>
    [javac]                                                  ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:134: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:145: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:156: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:167: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:179: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:595: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:606: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:617: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:628: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:640: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:1163: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:1174: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:1185: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:1196: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:1208: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:1757: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:1768: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:1779: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:1790: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:1802: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:2211: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:2222: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:2233: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:2244: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:2256: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]         com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:2896: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]           com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:292: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]           com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:759: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]           com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:1339: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]           com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:1922: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]           com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:2369: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ExtensionRegistryLite
    [javac] location: package com.google.protobuf
    [javac]           com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite extensionRegistry)
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/src/main/java/org/devtcg/five/server/HttpServer.java:333: warning: sun.misc.BASE64Decoder is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    [javac]                 userpassString = new String(new BASE64Decoder()
    [javac]                                                 ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:163: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method mergeDelimitedFrom(java.io.InputStream)
    [javac] location: class org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Artist.Builder
    [javac]       return newBuilder().mergeDelimitedFrom(input).buildParsed();
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:236: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method newUninitializedMessageException(org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Artist)
    [javac] location: class org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Artist.Builder
    [javac]           throw newUninitializedMessageException(result);
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:244: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method newUninitializedMessageException(org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Artist)
    [javac] location: class org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Artist.Builder
    [javac]           throw newUninitializedMessageException(
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:624: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method mergeDelimitedFrom(java.io.InputStream)
    [javac] location: class org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Album.Builder
    [javac]       return newBuilder().mergeDelimitedFrom(input).buildParsed();
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:697: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method newUninitializedMessageException(org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Album)
    [javac] location: class org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Album.Builder
    [javac]           throw newUninitializedMessageException(result);
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:705: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method newUninitializedMessageException(org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Album)
    [javac] location: class org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Album.Builder
    [javac]           throw newUninitializedMessageException(
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:1192: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method mergeDelimitedFrom(java.io.InputStream)
    [javac] location: class org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Song.Builder
    [javac]       return newBuilder().mergeDelimitedFrom(input).buildParsed();
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:1265: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method newUninitializedMessageException(org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Song)
    [javac] location: class org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Song.Builder
    [javac]           throw newUninitializedMessageException(result);
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:1273: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method newUninitializedMessageException(org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Song)
    [javac] location: class org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Song.Builder
    [javac]           throw newUninitializedMessageException(
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:1740: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method computeInt64SizeNoTag(long)
    [javac] location: class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream
    [javac]             .computeInt64SizeNoTag(element);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:1739: operator + cannot be applied to int,com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream.computeInt64SizeNoTag
    [javac]           dataSize += com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:1740: inconvertible types
    [javac] found   : <nulltype>
    [javac] required: int
    [javac]             .computeInt64SizeNoTag(element);
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:1786: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method mergeDelimitedFrom(java.io.InputStream)
    [javac] location: class org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Playlist.Builder
    [javac]       return newBuilder().mergeDelimitedFrom(input).buildParsed();
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:1859: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method newUninitializedMessageException(org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Playlist)
    [javac] location: class org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Playlist.Builder
    [javac]           throw newUninitializedMessageException(result);
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:1867: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method newUninitializedMessageException(org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Playlist)
    [javac] location: class org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Playlist.Builder
    [javac]           throw newUninitializedMessageException(
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:2240: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method mergeDelimitedFrom(java.io.InputStream)
    [javac] location: class org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.PlaylistSong.Builder
    [javac]       return newBuilder().mergeDelimitedFrom(input).buildParsed();
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:2313: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method newUninitializedMessageException(org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.PlaylistSong)
    [javac] location: class org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.PlaylistSong.Builder
    [javac]           throw newUninitializedMessageException(result);
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:2321: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method newUninitializedMessageException(org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.PlaylistSong)
    [javac] location: class org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.PlaylistSong.Builder
    [javac]           throw newUninitializedMessageException(
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:2566: package com.google.protobuf.Internal does not exist
    [javac]             new com.google.protobuf.Internal.EnumLiteMap<Type>() {
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:2764: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method mergeDelimitedFrom(java.io.InputStream)
    [javac] location: class org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Record.Builder
    [javac]       return newBuilder().mergeDelimitedFrom(input).buildParsed();
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:2837: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method newUninitializedMessageException(org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Record)
    [javac] location: class org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Record.Builder
    [javac]           throw newUninitializedMessageException(result);
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:2845: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method newUninitializedMessageException(org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Record)
    [javac] location: class org.devtcg.five.meta.data.Protos.Record.Builder
    [javac]           throw newUninitializedMessageException(
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] /home/vickey/code/five-server/gen/src/java/org/devtcg/five/meta/data/Protos.java:3312: internalBuildGeneratedFileFrom(java.lang.String,com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor[],com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor.InternalDescriptorAssigner) in com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor cannot be applied to (java.lang.String[],com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor[],com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor.InternalDescriptorAssigner)
    [javac]       .internalBuildGeneratedFileFrom(descriptorData,
    [javac]       ^
    [javac] 62 errors
    [javac] 2 warnings

BUILD FAILED
/home/vickey/code/five-server/build.xml:150: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/vickey/code/five-server/build.xml:76: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 5 seconds
```

I think some class definitions are not getting imported . How can I get rid of these errors?

EDIT: 
The cause of errors seems to be these lines in build.xml file

```
 73     <target name="compile" depends="init, build-props, protoc"                         description="compile the source">
 74         <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
 75         <javac srcdir="${src}:${gen.src}" destdir="${build.classes}"
 76                 debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source">
 77             <classpath refid="compile.classpath" />
 78         </javac>
 79     </target>
```

Here compile.classpath may not have those class definitions .

Comment: The cause of the error is not he highlighted lines of ANT. Instead you are missing at least one jar from your "compile.classpath" path. You have not explained how this path is populated. In most builds the 3rd party jars would be located in a directory called "lib" or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . After extracting and digging the Jar file(protobuf-2.0.3.jar) I have found that it does not contain the required class file.